# how to declare an array globally

Tags: iphone

hi i am new to iphone. what i am doing is declaring a NSMutable array named as labels, and that is declared in viewdidload.But when i access the label in buttonclick function it shows null. Previously i declred propery in .h file and initialize in init function also. please help where can i declare and how to declare a mutable array that is accesble any where in the class and how to add objects to it,that to the values are changeble dynamically. thanku

Comment: Try read docs: http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000138-DontLinkElementID_1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the array to be accessible anywhere in your class, you should declare it in your `@interface`. Your code should look something like this:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray *labels;
}
@end


@implementation MyViewController

 - (void)viewDidLoad {
    labels = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [labels addObject:@"Label"];
    // etc.
}

- (void)dealloc {
    // Don't forget to do this or your array will leak
    [labels release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)buttonClickHandler {
    // Do stuff with labels
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

you can declare them just as you would in C.  when I need them, I have an include file variables.h which contains something like

## ifdef GLOBAL

Int xyz;
Struct abc *ptr;

## else

External int xyz;
External struct abc *ptr;

## endif

in one .m file, do a #define GLOBAL

please excuse the typos, iPad is correcting me.

Comment: I don't think he's trying to create a global variable, but one that can be accessed from anywhere in the class. In any case, for global variables in the context of Objective-C, a singleton class would be more appropriate than declaring them as one would declare global C variables.